# Concatenate two files from separate folder into multiple folder

Tags: unix, merge, concatenation

I have folder containing files a1_1, a1_2, a2_1, a2_2, a3_1, a3_2 and folder in another directory containing b1_1, b1_2, b2_1, b2_2, b3_1, b3_2. Want to combine them into one new folder like this:

1_1 (Folder)
a1_1
b1_1

1_2 (Folder)
a1_2
b1_2

2_1 (Folder)
a2_1
b2_1

2_2 (Folder)
a2_2
b2_2

I am using UNIX, doing it one by one will be troublesome since I have 300 pairs of file that should be combined. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using basic bash scripting, here is an example on how to do it with comments explaining the steps.

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir_a=$1  // Directory containing a files given as first argument
source_dir_b=$2  // Directory containing b files given as second argument

a_files=$(ls $source_dir_a)  // Save list of files in provided a dir

for a_file in $a_files; do   // Loop over the files in the a dir
    echo "a_file=$a_file"
    folder=$(echo $a_file | sed -e 's/^a//g')  // Remove the leading "a" of a files using a regex for the storing folder name
    echo "folder=$folder"
    b_file=$(echo b$folder)  // Adding leading "b" to folder name to have b_file name
    echo "b_file=$b_file"
    mkdir $folder  // Create output folder
    mv $source_dir_a/$a_file $source_dir_b/$b_file $folder // Move the a and b files in output folder
done
```

What's missing is some error checking, especially if some expected files are not present.